# How to specify to use the modified field from select statement in group by (not the original one)

Tags: mysql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(`create`, "%d.%m.%Y") AS `create`
FROM table 
GROUP by `create`;
```

Is it possible to specify that I wanna use in GROUP BY the modified "create" from SELECT statement, instead of the original table field value?

In other words, you can specify it like table.create but how to do select.create

Comment: Did you try "GROUP BY 1" ? 1 being the column position you want to group by as it appears in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @ALombardo what will it do? group by create?

Comment: it'll group by the returned value for that position, so yes, it will use the modified create

Comment: @ALombardo this is the answer! thanks a lot!

Comment: @ALombardo and you may wanna add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-C). To use it as an identifier, delimit it with back-ticks, as you define the column alias and as you reference it in your GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(`create`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `create`
FROM `table`
GROUP by `create`
```

---

Update: Testing this, I see what you mean. It seems to use the column `create` of the base table instead of the alias. If I have two rows each on the same day but with different times, I'd expect those to be grouped together, but they are not.

```
mysql> insert into `table` values 
    ('2021-04-01 12:34:56'), 
    ('2021-04-01 14:34:56'), 
    ('2021-05-01 14:56:59'),
    ('2021-05-01 09:56:59');

mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`create`, "%d.%m.%Y") AS `create` 
    FROM `table`
    GROUP by `create`;
+------------+
| create     |
+------------+
| 01.04.2021 |
| 01.04.2021 |
| 01.05.2021 |
| 01.05.2021 |
+------------+
```

You could force it by putting the query with the date_format into a subquery:

```
mysql> SELECT `create` 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`create`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `create` 
        FROM `table`
    ) as t 
    GROUP BY `create`;
+------------+
| create     |
+------------+
| 01.04.2021 |
| 01.05.2021 |
+------------+
```

Or you could make sure your column alias is different from the column name of the base table:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.`create`, "%d.%m.%Y") AS `created` 
    FROM `table` t GROUP by `created`;
+------------+
| created    |
+------------+
| 01.04.2021 |
| 01.05.2021 |
+------------+
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as how I do it, fixed in my question.

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting way to solve it too, another one was in comments